# how to fix migration error to heroku - Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, migration

Not sure where I am going wrong. I looked over the [**Knex.js** docs](https://knexjs.org/#Builder) and have not found any issues in my code. My goal is to migrate from **Heroku** to **Postgres** but this error is the only blocker:

```
migration file "20190311161455_habits_table.js" failed
migration failed with error: alter table "habits" add constraint
"habits_categoryid_foreign" foreign key ("categoryId") references
"category" ("id") - relation "category" does not exist
```

This is my code:

```js
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('habits', tbl => {
    tbl.increments();

    tbl.string('habitTitle');
    tbl.boolean('completed').defaultTo(false);
    tbl.integer('completionPoints').defaultTo(0);
    tbl
      .integer('userId')
      .unsigned()
      .notNullable()
      .references('id')
      .inTable('users');


    tbl
      .integer('categoryId')
      .unsigned()
      .notNullable()
      .references('id')
      .inTable('category');
    tbl.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('habits');
};
```

Comment: "My goal is to migrate from Heroku to Postgres"—you mean migrate your Postgres database _on_ Heroku?

Comment: Does this migration work on your local Postgres database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, the error is very simple, the table `category` does not exits. Just create the table first or verify if the name is correct. Remember that, usually table names should be plural like, user->users or category->categories.